# How do I get multiple data sets on the same graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, spyder

I am importing three csv files containing data. I would like to graph these data sets on the same graph with the same axis. I was able to successfully graph my first data set without any hiccups but for some reason my other data sets are acting weird. I have tried plotting the data in excel and the result is normal. I can conclude that it must therefore be the fault of my code. I cannot see an error and would appreciate any help.

```
'diode 1N4004'
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv',header=None)

'diode1N914'
df1 = pd.read_csv('Data914.csv',header=None)

'diode 1N4148'
df2 = pd.read_csv('Data4148.csv',header=None)


t = df[0]
v = df[1]
a = df1[0]
d = df1[1]
h = df2[1]
d = df2[0]


# make a plot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))

'diode 1N4004'
ax.plot(t,v,lw=2) 
'diode1N914'
ax.plot(a,d,lw=2)
'diode 1N4148'
ax.plot(h,d,lw=2)



ax.set_xlabel('Voltage [V]',fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel('Current [$A$]',fontsize=14)
ax.set_title('Diode Voltages',fontsize=14)
```

[The output of the graph is shown below. The correct graph should be three exponentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Pqt.png)

Comment: how do the dataframes look like?

Comment: I see that you plot (h,d) which are index (1,0) the rest is index (0,1) can there be an error in your code of is that what you intended to do?

Comment: Tried changing (h,d) have even more obscure results.